# Behaviour explanation

Tags: java, jetty

Can someone explain why this code halts at startFileHTTP()? The jetty server starts but the rest of the program doesn't work. Do i need to look into multi-threaded programming?

```
try {
     startFileHTTP();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

public void startFileHTTP() throws Exception {
     Server server = new Server();
     SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
     connector.setPort(8080);
     server.addConnector(connector);

     ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
     resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
     resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });

     resource_handler.setResourceBase("/test");

     HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
     handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
     server.setHandler(handlers);

     server.start();
     server.join();
}
```

Console:

```
2011-02-10 13:55:47.828:INFO::jetty-7.1.6.v20100715
2011-02-10 13:55:47.953:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is that the very last line of the function is

```
server.join();
```

This function only returns when the `server` thread has finished running.  It seems like that's not what you want, since it looks like you want it to run in the background.  Getting rid of this line should fix this.

As an aside, you probably shouldn't be throwing `Exception` from `startFileHTTP`.  This makes it less clear what exceptions can be thrown and reduces the amount of information callers have about what sorts of errors they could expect to see.